# Sharepoint Fresh install how to set up site - getting _layouts/error.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have a fresh install of a Sharepoint site. The administration panel is all set up, but we need to set up a base Team site. I tried to create a site collection and use the Teamsite as our base but I keep getting the /_layouts/error.aspx.  How do you do a fresh site? There are tutorials all around on how to set up a team site once a site is already set up, but not one from a fresh install.  How do we set up a new site?  Kind of frustrated. 
We just get this error: An unexpected error has occurred. and it redirects to the /_layouts/error.aspx.

Any ideas? Thanks.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
The site we are trying to get to is actually a different site from our administration area than our public facing site.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have already created an Application? If not you have to do that first THEN you create a site UNDER that application. So for example, under Application Management, you create a new Application (Use claims based auth for best results), set the Port number (defaults to 80) and when that's done, it will prompt you if you want to create a site.

> > DON'T MAKE THE MISTAKE OF USING A TEAM SITE as the top level site if you are using Server (not foundation); a top level Team Site can only create Team Sites underneath it (i.e. No publishing).

If you do have an Application setup (so you know, an Application is the same as setting up a blank IIS site with a matching SharePoint DB), then it's something else. Setting up a site is usually not a problem under an application but it might be that you may have a permissions error; unfortunately cause of 99% of SP problems.

The only way to track this down is using the System Application Event Log and the SharePoint Log. Start with event log and see if any errors are there. If not open the SharePoint log (by default, c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs). SharePoint creates a new log every 30 min (again by default) - sort the folder by date and open the latest. Search for the first part of the correlation number (xxxxx-) without the dash - when you find the first occurence of it, scroll left in the editor to where the message is then start scrolling down. You can also simply try searching for "Error" or "Failure". The log can be hard to read so you can use the ULSViewer (download from here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer).

In many cases, this may be that the Application pool account does not have the right permissions to access the database.

If this doesn't help (or you can't figure it out), you can TEMPORARILY modify the web.config file - find 'customerrors="Off"' and change it to On (case sensitive!); you may need to do an IISReset (open a command window or Start > Run enter CMD then click OK) then enter IISreset; this stops and restarts the IIS. This turns off the error handling from SharePoint and will display the full error - TURN THIS BACK to Off when done!

If you are on a production system, do this after hours!!

That said, if you do see any errors and can't figure it out, repost here.

Best Regards,

David Sterling - CEO/CSA/Executive Consultant
david_sterling@sterling-consulting.com – +1 704-202-2282 – Skype: davidmsterling
Blog: http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com
Corp Site: http://www.sterling-consulting.com
Featured on: http://www.sharepoint-blog.com

Comment: we will check all these solutions out. I was not the initial person to install Sharepoint.  It looks like the person who did, did set up a web application on Port 80 but I don't know if they chose a site template or not.  I am not sure about the App Pool but we will check that out. I looked at the permissions in Sharepoint and it looks like that App has Full Control set.  We will check other the other solutions out.  If we don't find anything, we will comment back. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Quick question, what permissions should the Port 80 app have? We assume Full Control.
Right now we have Local Service set with Full Control under User Policy. Would there be any other service or user policy permissions under the Port 80 application that would need to be added?

Comment: Full control is not required - Local Service is the WRONG account, you must setup a separate domain account to use as the Application Service account and it must have user access to the SharePoint databases. Local Service will not work!